# Convert an address to a specific type in python gdb

Tags: python, c++, c, gdb

I have an user defined struct.

```
struct foo {
    int bar1;
    char *name;
    user_type_t *tba;
}foo_t;
```

While in gdb, I have an address that points to type foo_t.
e.g 0xfe83ba56 points to a structure in the memory that is of type foo_t.

I can convert that address to foo_t by type casting, and then I can dereference it if needed.
(gdb) p (foo_t *)0xfe83ba56

How do to the same with python inside gdb? If I have a gdb.Value object which already points to an object of type foo_t, then I can its address. but here, I'm trying to convert a raw address into a gdb.Value object.

I looked into https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Values-From-Inferior.html#Values-From-Inferior and lot of posts from the 'similar questions' section of SO, but couldn't find the exact answer.

Comment: I don't know the answer to this myself, but it occurs to me that a custom type printer will probably need to do exactly this, so maybe you can figure it out by looking at the custom type printers shipped with e.g. libstdc++?  https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=tree;f=libstdc%2B%2B-v3/python

Answer (score 6):

To cast, use the `Value.cast` method.  Something like:

```
t = gdb.lookup_type('foo_t').pointer()
value = value.cast(t)
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to add to your answer, I first converted the raw address into a gdb.Value of long type and then cast it to the type I wanted. It worked fine.
tv = gdb.Value(long(0xfffffe001ba43010, 16) // it was a 64 bit address
tf = tv.cast( gdb.lookup_type(‘foo_t’).pointer())

Comment: I got this far and I'm trying to figureo out how to cast to a pointer to a pointer, or in other words a pointer to an array of pointers. the pointer type doesn't have a pointer() function on it. any ideas?